# How Can I create a Hierarchical Pandas Dataframe from Several other Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Say I have 2 dataframes and each dataframe has the same columns but hold different types of information.

Example:

```
animals_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Dog', 'Cat'], 'B': ['Horse', 'Donkey']})
numbers_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
```

My goal is to create a hierarchical (also known as MultiIndex) dataframe where the first level is Animals & Numbers, and then the second level is column A and column B.

That is,

```
MultiIndex_data['Animals']

A   |   B
-----------
Dog | Horse
Cat | Donkey
```

and

```
MultiIndex_data['Numbers']

A | B
-----
1 | 3
2 | 4
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
pd.concat([animals_data, numbers_data], keys=['animal','number'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  animal         number   
       A       B      A  B
0    Dog   Horse      1  3
1    Cat  Donkey      2  4
```